# Getting Video using Node Js on Ar Drone v1.0

Tags: node.js-stream

How to get video stream or png stream using node js on the ar drone v1.0

I have been seeing the codes for v2.0 and even the gitHub people say that those libraries of video stream does not work with v1.

is there any other way I could get the png / video stream on the computer?

thanks and regards

Comment: If people say it does not work, it might not.  Have you tried to get it to work?  What error messages have you received?  What code have you tried that failed?  Please post some more detail.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response- Right so the people on the GIT hub they did say that v1.0 changed the video protocols which are not supported by the node js program for video.

Comment: The error that comes is TCP: ECONREFUSED

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I have struggled with producing a PNG (picture) stream or a TCP (video) stream from my Parrot AR Drones through Node.js. I am going to assume you already have Node.js installed and downloaded Felix Geisendörfer's Node.js package for AR-Drones, and that you have been able to fly it. To get the PNG stream, Make sure that you have 7zip installed (you'll need it) and you will also have to download FFMPEG so that your computer can easily parse the drone's stream before outputting it to your browser. Use 7zip to extract the FFMPEG files after downloading. Create a Node.js file (.js) and copy annd paste the following source code into it:

```js
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var http = require('http');
console.log('Connecting png stream ...');
var pngStream = arDrone.createClient().getPngStream();
var lastPng;
pngStream.on('error', console.log).on('data', function(pngBuffer) {
    lastPng = pngBuffer
});
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (!lastPng) {
        res.writeHead(503);
        res.end('Did not receive any png data yet.');
        return
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/png'
    });
    res.end(lastPng)
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Serving latest png on port 8080 ...')
});
```

Save the file as something like 'video.js' (as long as it ends in .js). Make sure the JavaScript file is set to run using Node.js (software you installed to fly the drone). Then, turn on your drone and connect to its wifi. Then, go through the FFMPEG files until you find a file called 'ff-prompt.bat'. In the prompt of that batch file, type or paste in the file path of your video.js (or whatever you called it). Then press enter and it should start broadcasting onto your localhost (127.0.0.1) at port 8080. So go to your browser and type "http://localhost:8080" and you should be able to see an image from your drone. If you have questions, feel free to leave a comment and I'll address it as soon as possible. Thanks!